# How to store values in an access database from a series of textboxes, labels?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledbconnection

[image: Design View]

Please refer to the image. I have a bunch of textboxes and labels (activity and dates - as shown in the image). I have to store the value of the labels (both activity name and column name) and the value that is entered by the user in the text box when the submit button below the table is clicked (not visible in picture).

I have given a unique ID to each row but I don't know how to make use of it to store values. I am just asking what approach to take here. I can post the code but that wouldn't be of much use as I couldn't understand how to store values.

Comment: i suggest using datagridview, so we can easily iterate.

Comment: @ManuVarghese I don't want to show the data record to every user. I just want to insert the values in the database without the user view.

Comment: i didn't get your question  can you be more specific ?